# mongodb command with sort and limit

Tags: java, mongodb

Hi i am trying to implement this exact command below using the Mongo Java api

```
db.system.profile.find({},{millis:1}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1);
```

I was thinking of doing something like below, but i am only expecting a single INT to be returned and this may be a wrong/long way of doing it.

```
Mongo mongoClient = new Mongo( "localhost" , 27017 );
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "user" );    
        /*  db.system.profile.find({},{millis:1}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1);*/
        DBCollection collTime = db.getCollection("system.profile");
        DBCursor cursor = collTime.find(new BasicDBObject("millis", 1),new BasicDBObject("$natural", -1)).limit(1);  
        System.out.println(cursor.toString());
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [*public DBObject findOne(DBObject o, DBObject fields, DBObject orderBy)*](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findOne%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29). Code would look something like this:

```
String str = collection.findOne(new BasicDBObject(), new BasicDBObject("millis", 1),
    new BasicDBObject("$natural", -1)).get("millis").toString();
```

Comment: Im getting (Cursor id=0, ns=user.system.profile, query={ "millis" : 1}, fields={ "$natural" : -1}, numIterated=0, limit=1, addr=localhost:27017, readPreference=ReadPreference.PRIMARY) any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Should your edit represent your current code? Then please read carefully my given answer: The function to call is **findOne(…)** instead of _find(…)_, the return value is a **DBObject** instead of a _DBCursor_ and the first parameter should be an **empty** _DBObject_ since it represents the query. Please copy and paste my code and try again.

Comment: Yes the update does represent my current code. I don't have access to that specific method for some reason so i was trying another way. Ill try find out why i don't have it. Thanks!

Comment: The method is available since version 2.9.0 - any chance to upgrade? Otherwise I think you have to go with your first approach.